# Data entry form, js

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this function:

```
function incolla(){
  var array=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  console.log(array);
  var dim1=array.length;
  var dim=arguments.length;

  for(var i=0, ; i<dim1-1 ; i++,){
    if(i>=3){
      array[i].value=arguments.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

That should paste the data into the form:

```
<td align="center">
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="risposta_4_0" name="risposta_4_0" size="2" onchange="javascript: setRespons2(4,0, this.value)" style="border:2px #444444 solid; background-color:#ffffff"> 
  <input type="text" id="risposta_4_1" name="risposta_4_1" size="2" onchange="javascript: setRespons2(4,1, this.value)" style="border:2px #444444 solid; background-color:#ffffff"> 
  <input type="text" id="risposta_4_2" name="risposta_4_2" size="2" onchange="javascript: setRespons2(4,2, this.value)" style="border:2px #444444 solid; background-color:#ffffff"> 
  <input type="text" id="risposta_4_3" name="risposta_4_3" size="2" onchange="javascript: setRespons2(4,3, this.value)" style="border:2px #444444 solid; background-color:#ffffff"> 
  <input type="text" id="risposta_4_4" name="risposta_4_4" size="2" onchange="javascript: setRespons2(4,4, this.value)" style="border:2px #444444 solid; background-color:#ffffff"> 
  <input type="text" id="risposta_4_5" name="risposta_4_5" size="2" onchange="javascript: setRespons2(4,5, this.value)" style="border:2px #444444 solid; background-color:#ffffff"> 
  <input type="text" id="risposta_4_6" name="risposta_4_6" size="2" onchange="javascript: setRespons2(4,6, this.value)" style="border:2px #444444 solid; background-color:#ffffff"> 
  <input type="text" id="risposta_4_7" name="risposta_4_7" size="2" onchange="javascript: setRespons2(4,7, this.value)" style="border:2px #444444 solid; background-color:#ffffff"> 
  <input type="text" id="risposta_4_8" name="risposta_4_8" size="2" onchange="javascript: setRespons2(4,8, this.value)" style="border:2px #444444 solid; background-color:#ffffff">
```

only that scirpt running the site does not take the value of the .value but by other parameters, how can I do to get around this problem?

Comment: **Suggestion:** Maybe you should start thinking about creating a `class`, asign that **CSS** to that class and delete those `style` attributes off your **HTML**. (I know it has nothing to do with your issues, but just saying!)

Answer (score 0):

[Reference mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

> The arguments object is not an Array. It is similar to an Array, but
>   does not have any Array properties except length. For example, it does
>   not have the pop method. However it can be converted to a real Array:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

You therefore want to update your javascript method to: ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q85yjk8L/))

```
function incolla(){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var array=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  console.log(array);
  var dim1=array.length;
  var dim=args.length;

  for(var i=0; i<dim1-1; i++){
    if(i>=3){
      array[i].value = args.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not that the values are loaded correctly only that the system of the website does not allow to add via .value, same thing happens to me in a different form (always the same site), where there are radio buttons, doing. click the system does not recognize them,